# R: Subsetting using a nonexistent variable gives no error

Tags: r, if-statement, brackets

While creating lead variables, I accidentally left out the lead variable by which my data is grouped. I was using brackets to insert an NA and there no was no error reported. To check my sanity, I did the same with ifelse and R created an error message. My concern is that if not for careful review, and some luck, I may never have known of my error.

How have others coded differently to make such less likely in the future (with minimal cost to time)? Also, are there other similar issues I should be aware of? Thanks, reproducible example is below.

```
dt <- data.frame(
group_name = c("D44", "D44","D44", "D45", "D45", "D47", "D47", "D47", "D47", "D48"),
order_number = sample(1:10))

dt$group_name <- as.character(dt$group_name) # so not a factor

dt <- dt[order(dt$group_name, dt$order_number),] # sort data

dt$lead1order_number <- c(dt$order_number[-1], NA)

# COMMENT OUT NEXT LINE AND RUN, no error with brackets, but one with ifelse
dt$lead1group_name <- c(dt$group_name[-1], NA) 

# done two different ways below
    # if group_name doesn't match lead1group_name, then lead1order_number NA
dt$lead1order_number[dt$group_name != dt$lead1group_name] <- NA  

dt$lead1order_number <- ifelse(dt$group_name != dt$lead1group_name, NA, dt$lead1order_number)
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Not sure what brackets you are referring to. Both lead/lagging make sense with or without a grouping variable. It all depends on what you are doing. This would be much easier with `dplyr`. Then you can use the `group_by()` command along with `mutate()` and `lead()` functions.

Comment: @MrFlick I am using using lags to see what the order_number is for the next order_number in the group_name. When this overlaps into the next group_name though I need to set it to NA. The overlap is identified by group_name != lead1group_name. When I set that condition within brackets, [dt$group_name != dt$lead1group_name], it doesn't give me an error even when lead1group_name doesn't exist. I agree dplyr is an option, but the point is to show the error when using brackets compared to ifelse (or dplyr).

Answer (score 1):

You question is a deep one. The issue with brackets aka subsetting is one of the key features of R. It's difficult to answer on your question in a comprehensive way. I just propose one of the possible simplest solutions:

```
# `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` ensures that strings will not be transformed to factors
dt <- data.frame(group_name = c("D44", "D44","D44", "D45", 
    "D45", "D47", "D47", "D47", "D47", "D48"),
    order_number = sample(1:10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dt <- dt[order(dt$group_name, dt$order_number),] # sort data
dt$lead1order_number <- c(dt$order_number[-1], NA)
# the example was slightly modified to demonstrate subsetting with NA
dt$lead1group_name <- c(dt$group_name[-c(1:2)], NA, "D")
```

Let's suppose, we need a column `"lead2group_name"`, which is missed in our data frame. The key issue which I propose to use is that the different subsetting methods give different results:

**simplifying** subsetting with `$` or `[[` will give nothing as a result:

```
print(dt$lead2group_name)
> NULL
```

**preserving** subsetting with `[` results in an error:

```
print(dt[ ,"lead2group_name", drop = FALSE])
```

> Error in [.data.frame(dt, , "lead2group_name") :  undefined columns
>   selected

I would use this issue to be sure that the requested column exists in the data.frame:

```
ind_of_non_match <- which(dt[ ,"group_name", drop = FALSE] != dt[ ,"lead1group_name", drop = FALSE])
ind_of_na <- which(is.na(dt[ , "lead1group_name", drop = FALSE]))
dt$lead1order_number[c(ind_of_non_match, ind_of_na)] <- NA
```

Note, please, that a one-step approach

```
dt$lead1order_number[(dt[ ,"group_name", drop = FALSE] != dt[ ,"lead1group_name", drop = FALSE])] <- NA
```

silently ignores `NA` values of `"lead1group_name"`. That don't seem to be the safest way. That is why I would rather use `which()` to separate non-matching of `"lead1group_name"` and `group_name` from presence of `NA` in the `"lead1group_name"`.

Hope, it'll be useful for your current work. As for your general concerns related to using of subsetting and assigment, you may find useful to have a look on `?Extract` of the R help and to study **subsetting** methods in more details using R tutorials.